# Reduce function in JS with multiply parameters?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have this class method:

```
public _controlValid(form: FormGroup, fieldName: string[], enableFieldName: string) {
    if (fieldName.map(field => {
      return form.controls[field].valid;
    }).reduce(function (a: number, b: number) {
      return a * b;
    })) {
      form.controls[enableFieldName].enable();
    } else {
      form.controls[enableFieldName].disable();
    }
  }
```

This piece of code iterates array of string and tries to get status each control. Then `reduce` multiples these returned values from `map`.

After compilinning I got this error message:

```
error TS2345: Argument of type '(a: number, b: number) => number' is not assignable to parameter of type '(previousVal
ue: boolean, currentValue: boolean, currentIndex: number, array: boolean[]) => boolean'.
  Types of parameters 'a' and 'previousValue' are incompatible.
    Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'number'.
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Now youre iterating fieldnames, returning if they're valid (so: `true`, `false`, `true`). And you're asking the runtime to `true * false * true` (apart from compiler errors)?

Comment: Looks like you're multiplying booleans.  Don't do that?

Comment: Yes, I multiply boolean, why not?

Comment: Why would you multiple a Boolean? You expect it to be 0 and 1, not true and false? Seems like you are trying to make sure it is all true or all false, seems like every() or some() is what you are after.

Comment: @epascarello: because it's Javascript, and you can, of course!

Comment: @ScottSauyet I can open a window with a hammer also. It works, but not the smartest choice.

Comment: @epascarello: Sorry, facetiousness doesn't come through well here.  Of course the OP shouldn't multiply booleans, at least not without explicitly converting them to numbers.  But the language does make such nonsense a little too easy to do!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that what you're trying to do is coerce the booleans to 0 or 1, multiply them to determine if there are any zeros, and coerce the resulting number back to a boolean for use in `if`.

Typescript does not like this idea.  While it would probably work in raw Javascript, Typescript says no.

You can fix this by replacing your `reduce` call with an `every` on the booleans:

```
function _controlValid(form: FormGroup, fieldName: string[], enableFieldName: string) {
  if (fieldName.map(field => {
    return form.controls[field].valid;
  }).every((a: boolean) => a)) {
    form.controls[enableFieldName].enable();
  } else {
    form.controls[enableFieldName].disable();
  }
}
```

If you have an `identity` function handy (`(x) => x`), then you could write `.every(identity)` more clearly.

### Cleaner

But something still bothers me about this code.  That `if` condition is really difficult to read.  I might break out two helper functions to clean it up:

```
const allTrue = (xs) => xs.every(x => x);
const fieldsValid = (controls, names) => names.map(n => controls[n].valid)

function _controlValid(form: FormGroup, fieldName: string[], enableFieldName: string) {
  if (allTrue(fieldsValid(form.controls, fieldName))) {
    form.controls[enableFieldName].enable();
  } else {
    form.controls[enableFieldName].disable();
  }
}
```

You might need some Typescript annotations on this.  But I find it much easier to follow when the conditional expression is shorter, preferably on one line.

Comment: First sample does not work: `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'valid' of undefined
    at app.component.ts:745
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)` on line `if (fieldName.map(field => {}`

Comment: Well, that's a part I didn't change, at least not intentionally.